# Uncaught Error: rails-ujs has already been loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am at the very beginning stage of creating a Rails app that uses React through the front-end, and I cannot get my test/setup component to load. I'm not sure where this problem is originating, or what I can do to solve it.

I've searched for similar errors, and there are some that are close, but none of the solutions fix my error. I've tried changing the embedded ruby to 'javascript_include_tag' and messing with the application.html.erb, but to no avail

***Application.html.erb***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SmartApartmentRailsAndReact</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

***app/views/static/index.html.erb***

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>

<%= react_component("HelloWorld", { greeting: "Hello" }) %>
```

***routes***

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static#index'
  namespace :v1, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    get 'things', to: 'things#index'
  end
end
```

***/app/controllers/v1/things_controller.rb***

```
class V1::ThingsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render json: { :things => [
            {
                :name => 'some-thing',
                :guid => '123'
            }
        ] }.to_json
    end
end
```

***app/controllers/static_controller.rb***

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` on your HEAD element, you don't need `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` on your index template.

Comment: Thank for the advice. When I remove it from the index the error is resolved, and I see the component in the dev tools, but not rendered.

Comment: You should open a new question since it's a different problem.

Comment: @user12091592 and you should accept this answer since it's correct.